# Test whether a file exists anywhere in the include path

Tags: php, include

I'm writing an autoload function and in the inner logic of it would like to test whether a certain file exists somewhere in the path prior to including it.

This is the logic:

If a file named `$className'.specialversion.php'` exists *anywhere* in the include path include it. Otherwise, let other autoloaders take care of including a file for this class.

At the moment I just do:  `@include($calculatedPath);`

I'm not sure if it's a good approach to include and suppress the error. I would rather check if the file exists (somewhere in the include path) prior to including it.

My question is:

- Can I test for existence of a file anywhere in the include path?
- Is it really problematic to do `@include($calculatedPath);`?

**Edit**

An important accent: I don't know where the file should be. I just want to know whether it exists in one of the directories in the include path. So I can't just do `file_exists()` or something like that.

Comment: of course it's really problematic. When your application stopped working with all files in place, you will know nothing of reasons.

Comment: This specific autoloader is intended to include a different version of the class if exists, so if not exists, it should just fallback to the next autoloader that in turn doesn't have any error suppression

Comment: again: when a different version of the class **exists**, but weren't loaded, your application will stop working and you will know nothing of the reasons.

Comment: Doing `file_exists` is pointless. Just add the include paths you want to search and/or stack an autoloader. If the file does not exist, there will be a warning. Supressing the error is bad practise. Please read the [documentation for `include` in the PHP Manual](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As of PHP 5.3.2 there is the option to use the [`stream_resolve_include_path()`](http://php.net/stream_resolve_include_path) function whose purpose is to

> Resolve [a] filename against the include path according to the same rules as fopen()/include() does.

If the file exists on one of the include paths, then that path (including the file name) will be returned. Otherwise (i.e. the file was not on any of the include paths) it will return `FALSE`.

Relating this to your needs, your autoloader might look something like:

```
function my_autoloader($classname) {
    $found = stream_resolve_include_path($classname . '.specialversion.php');
    if ($found !== FALSE) {
        include $found;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid the error supressor operator `@`.

```
function autoload($class) {
   // Build path (here is an example).
   $path = DIR_CLASSES .
           strtollower(str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class)) .
           '.class.php';

   if (file_exists($path)) {
       include $path;
   }
}

spl_autoload_register('autoload'); 

$front = new Controller_Front; 
// Loads "application/classes/controller/front.class.php" for example.
```

#### Update

> An important accent: I don't know where the file should be, I just want to know whether it exists in one of the directories in the include path. So I can't just do file_exists or something like this

If your class could be in a number of directories, you could...

- Have your autoload function traverse them all, looking for the class. I would not recommend this.
- Rename your classes to have a name that easily maps to a file path, like in the example code above.

If you do decide to traverse all folders looking for the class, and it becomes a bottleneck (benchmark it), you could benefit from caching the class name to file location mapping.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [`file_exists`](http://php.net/file_exists) rather than a warnings-suppressed include.

Then you'll have to iterate through the `include_path`:

```
$paths = explode(';', get_include_path());
foreach($paths as $p){
    if(file_exists($p . '/' . $calculatedPath)){
        include $p . '/' . $calculatedPath;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this better than trying, i.e. : @include? In my case this is never the last autoloader, and this one is only responsible of loading a special version of the class *if it exists*. So falling back to the next autoloader is the desired behavior for not found include file

Comment: I'm reluctant of running this loop because it sounds to me like it will lower efficiency unnecessarily

Comment: You should probably explode by `PATH_SEPARATOR` and then concatenate by `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` just to be safe :)

Answer (score 0):

I've written a function that can test it nicely

```
function fileExists($file) {
    if(function_exists('stream_resolve_include_path'))
        return stream_resolve_include_path($file);
    else {
        $include_path = explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path());
        foreach($include_path as $path)
            if(file_exists($path.DS.$file))
                return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a simple resolution, you should a test within the SPL-function file_get_contents() by setting the second argument to TRUE.

--Rolf